# Allow only one model in Backbone collection to have an active property at any given time

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my Backbone.js application I have a collection of models.

These models can be 'active' or not. When one model becomes active I want to ensure every other model in the collection is or becomes not active.

Currently I am achieving this by caching the currently active model, listening for change events and determining whether I should set the cached model to not active.

This works, BUT, it doesn't scale well. Not as I start adding more and more properties that should only be positive on one model per collection I finding duplicated the code is messy.

Any suggestions guys?

Here is my code

```
EOT.Collection.VehiclesBase = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : EOT.Model.Vehicle,
    currentOpen : false,
    initialize : function(){
        this.on('change:open', this.ensureSingleOpen);
    },
    ensureSingleOpen : function(changed){
        //ensure the last open vehicle closes
        if(changed!=this.currentOpen) {
            if(this.currentOpen){
                this.currentOpen.set('open',false);
            }
            if(changed.get('open')){
                this.currentOpen = changed;
                this.trigger('change:currentOpen');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you want pretty cleanly using the built in `each` function:

```
EOT.Collection.VehiclesBase = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : EOT.Model.Vehicle,
    initialize : function(){
        this.on('change:open', this.ensureSingleOpen);
    },
    ensureSingleOpen : function(changed){
        this.each(function(m) {
            m.set({open: m === changed}, {silent: true});
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hm, interesting, will try it and get back to you.

Comment: This code isn't quite suitable. It depends on two events firing or the last event firing to be a change to open. When this order isn't observed (which might not be in my control) it ends up behaving strangely.

Comment: I don't quite follow you. Why are there two events?

Comment: Ha that is a very good question. I did a test case and your answer works - thanks for the help, ill figure out why my events are firing twice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems that @net.uk.sweet answer has a minor syntax issue - i.e. this.each should probably be invoked instead of being set.

```
EOT.Collection.VehiclesBase = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : EOT.Model.Vehicle,
    initialize : function(){
        this.on('change:open', this.ensureSingleOpen);
    },
    ensureSingleOpen : function(changed){
        this.each(function(m) {
            m.set({open: m === changed}, {silent: true});
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip; that's what happens when you answer a question after your bedtime ;). I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Backbone Picky](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.picky)!

It's a really lightweight Backbone library that is easy to use.  It sounds great for what you are looking to do.

Specifically, you would want to use Picky.SingleSelect (taken from the github docs):

**Picky.SingleSelect:**

Creates single-select capabilities for a Backbone.Collection, allowing a single model to be exclusively selected within the colllection. Selecting another model will cause the first one to be deselected.